# Gitlab CI Runner command line doesn't care about --parameters

Tags: batch-file, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to write a windows batch file to automate the gitlab runner registration :

```
SET /p token=Token ?:
gitlab-runner register --locked false --run-untagged true --tag-list java --name foo --token %token% --url https://myurl --executor
```

I found the parameters in help documentation (`gitlab-runner register --help`) but it doesn't care about them. It still continues to ask question whose answers are in the parameters.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/gitlab-ci-runner-command-line-doesnt-care-about-parameters/2642#2642):

You're missing the `--non-interactive` tag to your registration command.

Full command should be:

```
gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --locked false --run-untagged true --tag-list java --name foo --registration-token %token% --url https://myurl --executor shell
```

Relevant documentation for [non-interactive registration](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/commands/README.md#non-interactive-registration).